# performance of windows in mac os with parallels.?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I'm currently using Core i3 + 8gb + intel 510 ssd as my main desktop.

If I install a copy of parallels on the following macbook, would it be same as my current setup?

Macbook: 2011 Macbook pro 13''
Ram: upgraded to 8gb

Comment: CPU benchmarks should be similar, but going from desktop SSD to portable HDD might be frustrating....

Comment: This needs more information. Is your main desktop currently a Windows PC (I'm assuming it is). Does your Macbook Pro have an SSD in it, or one of the factory installed 5400 RPM drives? What kind of Windows use are you looking for - business applications, numbers heavy programs, games?

Comment: @EpiGrad I've wrote that I'm using a MacBook Pro with SSD.

Comment: @Moon No, you actually didn't. You wrote about an unknown "Main Desktop" with an SSD, and then a Macbook Pro where you only specified the RAM. Mort's answer suggests I'm not the only one who is confused.

Comment: @EpiGrad //  I think I confused you and other users. I'm using my laptop (in this case macbook pro 13) as my desktop mainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, they could indeed be similar.

Parallels, in and of itself, should run just fine on your Macbook Pro. And, assuming the specs of your Macbook Pro are similar to your desktop (processor and SSD), the performance of your Parallels virtual machine should be similar. That, of course, also assumes that you have the virtual machine specifications the same between both machines (i.e., how much memory you allocate for the virtual machine, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear (to me) what your new Macbook Pro's configuration is / will be? Does it have the same Intel processor as your current setup? Does it have a solid state drive?

Just for comparison I have a Macbook Pro 2011 i7, 8 gigabytes RAM, with 128 gig SSD and I run Parallels 6 to allow me to run Windows 7 Enterprise. It work perfectly and I have zero issues moving back and forth between Lion and Windows 7 in Parallels 6.

My Windows 7 Enterprise VM has 2 gigabytes or RAM allocated with full Aero Interface options enabled. I run the VM locally (on SSD).

Comment: Your i7 is a bit heftier than i3 and any of the CTO/stock processors shipping on a 2011 13" MBP. Good advice though on the storage mattering.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 8Gb RAM makes the difference.  I'm running Snow Leopard on several 2009 macs and I was often seeing page outs when I had only 4Gb of RAM.  Upgrading to 8Gb drove the page outs to zero.  Switching back and forth between OS's was stutter-free and yielded a much better user experience.

My Windows OS is XP but I expect having adequate RAM would improve all virtual machine implementations.  I allocated 3 Gb to the Windows OS.